# How can I “clipToBottomBounds”?

Tags: ios, swift, clip

`clipsToBounds = true` clips the bounds on all 4 sides.

I would like to clip the bottom bounds only, and allow overflow of the top, left and right bounds.

How would I go about doing that in Swift 4?

Comment: There is no such thing. There is no fuzziness in clipsToBounds. Either its all or none.

Comment: You need to draw a Layer , or show Expected Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add masking layer with size much high on given side on which you want masking.

You can use following code for masking only from bottom side.

```
let maskingLayer = CALayer()
maskingLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
maskingLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 500); 

myView.layer.mask = maskingLayer;
```

You can change frame of maskingLayer to mask different sides that you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know that "masking layers" existed.  This seems to be exactly what I need.